# Terminating connection because of crash of another server process -Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Everytime i run the same query i'm getting this error:

`DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
connection to server was lost`

I'm using phpPgAdmin 5.1.

Comment: Do you think perhaps some details of the query might be helpful?

Answer (score 8):

A concurrent query in a different database session has crashed its server backend process. As a consequence, the whole database stops and performs crash recovery from the latest checkpoint.

You should look into the database server log to see what the problem is.